# Calling an async function from within a do/while loop

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to iterate over values returned from the DB, which are retrieved by an async function I declared in a different place. Using node-postgres, very straightforward:

```
exports.getHandshakes = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.query(`
        select count(*) as activeHandshakes, (select user_id from handshakes order by random() limit 1) as randomHandshake from handshakes`)
        const { activeHandshakes, randomHandshake } = result.rows[0]
        return { activeHandshakes, randomHandshake }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function from a do/while loop, so I run it once and then check if I have to call it again, like so:

```
registerHandhsake(message.data.origID);
let tries = 0;
let recipientID;
const { activeHandshakes } = getHandshakes();
do {
  let { randomHandshake } = getHandshakes();
  recipientID = randomHandshake;
  console.log('checking', recipientID)
  tries++;
} while (
  tries < activeHandshakes &&
  randomHandshake !== message.data.origID &&
  message.data.previousTries.indexOf(recipientID) > 0
);
```

With the code like this, recipientID is undefined and the values are returned from the DB way too late for this to work.

I tried using a promise:

```
Promise.resolve(randomHandshake).then( randomHandshake => recipientID = randomHandshake )
```

but I get the same issue.

How can I tell it to actually wait for the results before continuing?

Edit: added `console.log('checking', recipientID)` as "debugging" stage

Comment: "*How can I tell it to actually wait for the results before continuing?*" use `await` in front of `getHandshakes()`. That's how you make wait before you continue. You then have to make `registerHandhsake` an `async` as well.

Comment: I added console log to see what the value of `recipientID` is using your `async/await` suggestion and I get `checking undefined`

Comment: Because `getHandshakes();` returns a promise and promises don't have `randomHandshake` property. You have to `await` the promise to get the resolved value out of it and *that* resolved value has a `randomHandshake` property.

Comment: thank you for taking the time for this. I started digging a bit further on why I was getting an undefined if I was supposed to be getting values already and turned out to be an issue with the destructuring.